# Get date in php in 2 weeks

Tags: php, datetime

```
$addhr = time() + (1 * 13 * 60 * 60);
$curDateTimeMil= date("Y-m-d G:i:s",$addhr);
echo $curDateTimeMil;
```

This will echo `2010-08-27 16:21:31`.

How can I get the date after 2 weeks? (sept 10)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you expect `1 * 13 * 60 * 60` does?

Comment: There is also a example in the [PHP date() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) how to achieve this. Read Example #3. But strtotime would be a solid solution (@jensgram).

Answer (score 30):

```
$dateInTwoWeeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');
```

See [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

---

*Update #1*: Yes, this is the lazy way to do it. However, I do believe that the *possible* negative performance impact is countered by the positive effect on readability / understanding of the code. Should performance be an issue, one could switch to native (integer-based) time manipulation (and add comments).

---

*Update #2*: The optional second argument is the reference date. E.g.:

```
strtotime('+2 weeks', mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 1984)); // 8th Feb. 1984 + 2 weeks
```

Comment: how can i specify the start date before obtaining the date in 2 weeks?

Comment: By accepting answers to some of your previous questions :-)
Or reading the documentation. Or using `time()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the starting time (from where to calculate) using `mktime()`.

Example: Two week after September 10, 2010 (i.e. +14 days):

```
 $date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 10 + 14, 2010);
```

To get just the DATE (not time) of two weeks later (+14 days) from today:

```
 $date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+14, date("Y")));
```

And this gives with TIME of two weeks later (+14 days) from now:

```
 $date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s", mktime(date("G"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d")+14, date("Y")));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply add the number seconds of two weeks:

```
2 weeks = 2 · 7 days = 14 days
        = 14 · 24 hours = 336 hours
        = 336 · 60 minutes = 20160 minutes
        = 20160 · 60 seconds = 1209600 seconds
```

So:

```
$curDateTimeMil += 1209600;
// or
$curDateTimeMil += 2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

Comment: With the tiny caveat that you may miss the right day if you're unlucky enough to fall into a daylight savings switchover or leap second... :)

Comment: @deceze: That’s not an issue with the time but with the representation of the time.