# PHP Form that returns an error if the selected date is outside a specific range - Using wordpress functions.php within a woocommerce store

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, date, woocommerce

Background - New to coding (loving it but slightly overwhelmed at times)

The title pretty much says it all, I am trying to add a checkout function where the customer must select a date at least two weeks after the current date. I was able to find resources to modify the cart page and how to add fields, but my lack of php knowledge has prevented me from improving the overall functionality and behaving the way I'd like it to.

Below is the code I added to the child theme. Thank you so so much in advance for the help!!!

```
/**
 * Add Pickup Date to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_pickup_date' );

function my_custom_checkout_pickup_date( $checkout ) {
    
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_pickup_date"><h3>' . __('Pickup Date') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'pickup_date', array(
        'type'          => 'date',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Select a date on or after 12/22/2020'),
        'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'pickup_date' ));

    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';

}

/**
 * Error Message for Pickup Date
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_pickup_date_process');

function my_custom_checkout_pickup_date_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['pickup_date'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a pickup date for this order.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify "min" and "max" values as custom attributes.
Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54280760/154978) of how to specify custom attributes.
Do calculate the dates relative to "today" you can use `strtotime` and `mktime` , see this question's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582435/get-date-in-php-in-2-weeks) to get a hold on this.